# Using polymorphic type in type family in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm learning about type family, but it's so confusing. When I define a polymorphic type outside of class definition, it works well.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
type T = Num a => a
```

But when polymorphic type defined inside of class definition,

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

data D = D

class A a where
    type T a :: *
instance A D where
    type T D = Num a => a
```

then complier shows error :

```
Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: forall a. Num a => a
In the type instance declaration for 'T'
In the instance declaration for 'A D'
```

Is there a way to make a function in class whose return type is polymorphic, like as 3(Num a => a)?

Comment: Can you add an example where you would like to use such a thing? I think that `Num a => a` as return type might be a lot less useful than you expect.

Comment: Type synonyms and associated type families (and non-associated type families as well) behave the same in many instances but are actually different beasts. A type synonym essentially just performs syntactic substitution. The type checker is not aware of your type synonyms. A type family application may require information about surrounding types to resolve, so the type checker must deal with them. As for fixing this error, define `newtype X = X (forall a.Num a => a)` and `type Ed D = X`.